# Excel - compare and replace cell value based on a value in another table or column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison, formula

I have one column with countries acronymns

SHEET 1

```
+------------------+
| Country_Acronym  |
+------------------+
| EG               |
| AE               |
| PK               |
| IN               |
| LK               |
+------------------+
```

I have another sheet with corresponding titles

SHEET 2

```
+------------------+----------------------+
| Country_Acronym  |     Country_Name     |
+------------------+----------------------+
| EG               | Egypt                |
| AE               | United Arab Emirates |
| PK               | Pakistan             |
| IN               | India                |
| LK               | Sri Lanka            |
+------------------+----------------------+
```

I need a formula to read the value on the first column of the first sheet and replace the value with the country_name on the 2nd sheet.
So, when you find EG replace with Egypt, when you find PK replace with Pakistan etc

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? [It appears no attempt has been made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of cell itself depending on the value within that very self cell - without using VBA.

Instead you may use the below formula on the `B2` of Sheet1 & copy down, then copy that column, paste onto `Col:A` as **Values Only**.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```